# Identifying packages from my app

Tags: android

I have a few projects that I include in my app as libraries.  I'd like to write a method that scans for which of these projects are included.  What I'm trying to do here is identify which libraries (my own) are included in any given build of my app.

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

The above line seems to give me all the packages on the device, but I specifically want the packages bundled in my app.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  Any ideas?  Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above line seems to give me all the packages on the device

Yes, where "packages" refers to APKs.

> I  specifically want the packages bundled in my app

You have no packages bundled in your app.

> I have a few projects that I include in my app as libraries. I'd like to write a method that scans for which of these projects are included.

Then you will need to roll your own code for this. For example, you could use `Class.forName()` to see if a particular Java class from a particular library exists in your virtual machine or not.